# What to use in Python to remember variable between loops

Tags: python

first of all I'm just beginning my journey with Python (so you can also ignore all hideous semicolons). It is a simple program as a task at the end of chapter checking what you have learned. Basically it's a "guess the number" but the program has to guess your number (it's a reversed program from book).
Maybe it's not the intention of the book and I've yet not learned it but my curiosity took the best of me and I have to ask. How can you remember variables between loops? I think I have to use table and in that way save and check variables between loops, but maybe there is an easier way in Python itself.

In code the program remembers last number it generated but another one is "forgotten" - obviously visable in code. The purpose of this is to minimise attempts of program to guess the number (narrow numbers that are guessed).
code to get the idea of program:

```
#Program Switcheroo, what is the number?

import random;

print("\t Welcome to game 'What is the number?' where you are picking number!");
print("\nRules are simple and based on your honesty ;)");
print("Think of number between 1 and 100, computer will try to guess it.");
print("If the number is too big you type 'too big', too small 'too small'");
print(", and if computer guessed it right 'right'");
print("\nEverything clear? Let's start!");

guess = random.randint(1, 100);
tries = 1;

print("Your number is...",guess,"?");
print("Answer 'too big', 'too small', 'right'"); 
number = input();
while number != "right":
    if number == "too big":
        tries += 1;
        guess = random.randint(1, guess);
        print ("Your number is...",guess,"?");
        print("Answer 'too big', 'too small', 'right'");
        number = input();
    elif number == "too small":
        tries += 1;
        guess = random.randint(guess, 100);
        print ("Your number is...",guess,"?");
        print("Answer 'too big', 'too small', 'right'");
        number = input();
    else:
        print("Ups!");
        break;
print("I won in", tries, "tries!");

input("\n\nTo end app, press Enter.");
```

Comment: To store multiple values in a variable, use a compound data structure like a list, set or dict…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to do the following optimisation (there are few things to do in order to improve the quality of the code, like remove duplicated code and use functions instead but I will leave it for you):

You can manage lower and upper bounds for your guesses and update it for every guess - if your guess is X and it's too big, all the future guess must be less than X so your upper bound is going to be X-1 (and same for the lower bound).

Here is a basic implementation:

```
guess = random.randint(1, 100)
tries = 1
print("Your number is...", guess, "?")
print("Answer 'too big', 'too small', 'right'")
number = input()
upper_bound = 100
lower_bound = 1
while number != "right":
    if number == "too big":
        upper_bound = guess-1 if guess < upper_bound else upper_bound
        tries += 1
        guess = random.randint(lower_bound, upper_bound)
        print(f"lower bound: {lower_bound}, upper bound: {upper_bound}")
        print("Your number is...", guess, "?")
        print("Answer 'too big', 'too small', 'right'")
        number = input()
    elif number == "too small":
        lower_bound = guess+1 if guess > lower_bound else lower_bound
        print(f"lower bound: {lower_bound}, upper bound: {upper_bound}")
        tries += 1
        guess = random.randint(lower_bound, upper_bound)
        print("Your number is...", guess, "?")
        print("Answer 'too big', 'too small', 'right'")
        number = input()
    else:
        print("Ups!")
        break
print("I won in", tries, "tries!")

input("\n\nTo end app, press Enter.")
```

In this implementation, you don't have to "remember" all your guesses so your memory footprint will be smaller and number of tries will be minimal.

I added a print to the lower and upper bounds in each iteration for debug purposes - to show you how the bounds are changing.

Comment: it is a method to this "madness" and it will work but my idea was. If it rolls 70 and you say too big program will throw away numbers >= 70 and won't roll anything from that range.

Comment: " If it rolls 70 and you say too big program will throw away numbers >= 70" and this is not what you want? to make it more efficient?

Comment: this is exactly what I want, but maybe I understand the method proposed above wrong. I understand if it gets upper_bound -1 it will change it from 100 to 99 doesn't? But I would like to change it to 69 at one go.

Comment: It will change it to 69. Try to run it and see how the bounds are changing and let me know it doesn't work as you expected...

Comment: ok tested it, works like a charm. BUT it needs exepction when player lies :P but that is optimization on my head. Thank you for answer. (ValueError: empty range for randrange() (61,61, 0))

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list. Before your loop, declare an empty list

```
attempted_values = set()
```

When you choose a number to guess, append it to that list

```
attempted_values.add(number)
```

When you choose a number to guess, you should also check if it is in the list and if it is, find another number

```
if (number in attempted_values):
    number is in the list
```